# BSOD when hibernating while VirtualBox is open

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, bsod, hibernate

I have a recurring problem where I get a blue screen of death when I hibernate my computer while I have VirtualBox open. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit with a xubuntu on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) guest. I'm also using version 4.3.30 of virtualbox and version 4.3.24 of the guest additions. My BSOD provided the following information: the error was a DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, and was attributed to VBoxNetFlt.sys. I ran WinDbg on the MEMORY.DMP (full dump, not minidump) and got the following info:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Summary Dump File: Only kernel address space is available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7601.18741.amd64fre.win7sp1_gdr.150202-1526
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`0300f000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03253890
Debug session time: Fri Apr 10 15:50:18.376 2015 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 3 days 14:35:58.020
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...........................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
................................
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck A, {112337, 2, 0, fffff80003076615}

*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for avgidsdrivera.sys
Probably caused by : avgidsdrivera.sys ( avgidsdrivera+10634 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000112337, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80003076615, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000112337 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KiInsertQueueApc+69
fffff800`03076615 488b4108        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+8]

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff8800bffb710 -- (.trap 0xfffff8800bffb710)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=fffff80003341a58 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=000000000011232f
rdx=fffffa800a6373e0 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80003076615 rsp=fffff8800bffb8a0 rbp=fffff880009e8180
 r8=0000000000000001  r9=000000000011231f r10=fffff880009e8c01
r11=fffffa800fd26b00 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
nt!KiInsertQueueApc+0x69:
fffff800`03076615 488b4108        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+8] ds:00000000`00112337=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80003083469 to fffff80003083ec0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`0bffb5c8 fffff800`03083469 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00112337 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`0bffb5d0 fffff800`030820e0 : fffff880`0bffb738 fffff800`03083153 ffffffff`8000297c fffffa80`105c1060 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`0bffb710 fffff800`03076615 : fffff880`00000001 fffffa80`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`0bffb8a0 fffff800`030656b0 : fffffa80`105c1060 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000078 fffffa80`0a6373d0 : nt!KiInsertQueueApc+0x69
fffff880`0bffb8d0 fffff880`04c10634 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`778e7ac0 00000000`00000078 00000000`000007ff : nt!KeInsertQueueApc+0x80
fffff880`0bffb930 fffff880`04c107b4 : 00000000`0000ed04 fffff880`04c3cf50 ffffffff`8000397c fffffa80`1769b6c0 : avgidsdrivera+0x10634
fffff880`0bffba10 fffff880`04c10866 : ffffffff`8000397c fffffa80`1769b6c0 fffffa80`168f6520 00000000`000007ff : avgidsdrivera+0x107b4
fffff880`0bffbac0 fffff880`04c2925c : 00000000`00000001 fffff880`0bffbba8 fffffa80`0fd26b50 fffff880`0bffbba8 : avgidsdrivera+0x10866
fffff880`0bffbb10 fffff800`0337cb43 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0fd26b50 : avgidsdrivera+0x2925c
fffff880`0bffbb40 fffff800`0308da95 : fffff800`03338b00 fffff800`0322b201 fffffa80`0fd26b00 fffffa80`00000000 : nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x23
fffff880`0bffbb70 fffff800`03322b8a : fffffa80`105029d0 fffffa80`0fd26b50 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`0698eb30 : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x111
fffff880`0bffbc00 fffff800`030758e6 : fffff880`03365180 fffffa80`0fd26b50 fffffa80`06d40290 00000000`07fa1011 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`0bffbc40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`0bffc000 fffff880`0bff6000 fffff880`0bffb8a0 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
avgidsdrivera+10634
fffff880`04c10634 84c0            test    al,al

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  5

SYMBOL_NAME:  avgidsdrivera+10634

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: avgidsdrivera

IMAGE_NAME:  avgidsdrivera.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  55128c2a

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_avgidsdrivera+10634

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_avgidsdrivera+10634

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Please provide any assistance you can on determining the cause of and solution to this problem.

Comment: have you tried using the current version of Vbox?

Answer (score 1):

The crash [IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seams to be caused by the driver `avgidsdrivera.sys`

```
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: X64_0xA_avgidsdrivera+10634
```

which is part of AVG AntiVirus.

Make sure AVG is up to date and if nothing helps, [uninstall AVG](https://support.avg.com/SupportArticleView?l=en_US&urlname=How-to-uninstall-AVG).